# This diagram needs fixing... And I don't know how to fix it

Tags: tikz-cd

This is my diagram so far

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
& \  \ O \arrow[r, "\phi_{1}", yshift=0.7ex] \arrow[r, "\phi_{2}"', yshift=-0.2ex] & P \\
X \arrow[ddr, dashleftarrow, "u_{1}"']\arrow[ddr, bend right, "e'"']\arrow[dr, "e"] \arrow[ur, "el_{1}"] \arrow[rr, "f"] && Y \arrow[ul, "el_{2}"] \\
& I \ \arrow[d, "\exists!\nu"', xshift=-0.1ex] \arrow[ur, hookrightarrow, "m", yshift=-0.2ex] \\
& I' \arrow[uuu, crossing over, "w", xshift=1ex] \arrow[uur, hookrightarrow, bend right, "m'"', yshift=-0.3ex] \arrow[uur, dashrightarrow, "u_{2}"', xshift=0.1ex]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The formatting is a bit messed up, and I don't know how to fix it. Some of the arrows are too short, and some of the arrows are unaligned. For w: I' --> O, I got it cross over the arrow f, but it went through I and made it completely disappear, so I had to shift it to the right... How could I make the w: I' --> O cross over/under I? Can you do it for objects? O just arrows?... How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome! Can you indicate what you would like to change? On my machine the result looks OKish. However, I do not know how you embed it in a document, this can change things. So please also add a complete minimal working example, which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: You are using `center` within displaystyle math mode...

Comment: @Fractalisattopanswers.xyz it isn't aligned in the center if I remove the center

Comment: You can remove `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat how can I make my diagram appear in this thread?

Comment: There is a button for that above the text area. Just hover the mouse over these symbols, then the tool tip will tell you which one it is.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I can't find that anywhere!

Comment: Then please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. You also can use CTRL+G.

Comment: I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkOmp.png), using the final version of TL2019. I suppose it is fine.

Comment: @Fractalisattopanswers.xyz yeah, that's what I have, but this in is paper that I'm going to be submitting into LaTeX, and a lot of the formatting here is a bit choppy and bad...

Comment: @BrandonBattye Then please add more information so that we can reproduce the behaviour in our own machines

Comment: Why you not simply bend this arrow (I' -- O)?

Comment: @Zarko I tried that.... One, it looks messy, and two, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I would draw your diagram as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
    & O \ar[r, "\phi_{1}",shift left] \ar[r, "\phi_{2}"',shift right] 
        & P \\
X \ar[ur, "el_{1}"] \ar[rr, "f"] \ar[ddr, dashleftarrow, "u_{1}"']
  \ar[ddr, bend right, "e'"']\ar[dr, "e"]  
    &   & Y \ar[ul, "el_{2}" '] \\
    & I \ar[d, "\exists!\nu"'] \ar[ur, hookrightarrow, "m"] 
        &                      \\
    & I' \ar[uuu, crossing over, "w", bend right=20] % <---
         \ar[uur, hookrightarrow, bend right, "m'"']
         \ar[uur, dashrightarrow, "u_{2}"']
         & \\
\end{tikzcd}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much :)